# How can live update of marker position on google map?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have a list of coordinates which comes from database which is updated every 10 second .i want to show places based on my coordinate in 10 second interval.how can i set on Google Map.
I am initialize map by this code.

```
function InitializeMap() 
{
directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(17.425503, 78.47497);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 13,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("divGoogleMap"), myOptions);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use markup object ?

Answer (score 0):

add the markers every 10 seconds, and every time get the locations with ajax call.

```
var myVar = setInterval(function(){addMarkers()},10000);

        function addMarkers(){
            var coorArr = (get the coordinates from your database with ajax)
            marker.setMap(null); //hide markers
            for(var i=0; i<coorArr.length; i++){
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: coorArr[i],
                title:"place"+i
            });
            }
         marker.setMap(map)//show the markers
        }
```